# Using rvalue in the condition statement of `for` loop in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop, mutex, rvalue

I am working on a programming task that takes in an `n` value and uses three threads to print *zero*, *even* and *odd* numbers.

For example, if `n = 3`, it will print `010203`. I encountered a strange behavior that when rvalue is used in the condition check in a for loop, my program just hangs entirely without doing anything. This phenomenon only appears in multithreading program. Thus, I put the entire code here:

```cpp
#include <functional>  // function
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>   // mutex
#include <thread>  // thread

using namespace std;

class ZeroEvenOdd {
  private:
    int n;
    mutex zero_mtx, even_mtx, odd_mtx;

  public:
    ZeroEvenOdd(int n) {
        this->n = n;
        zero_mtx.unlock();

        even_mtx.lock();
        odd_mtx.lock();
    }

    // printNumber(x) outputs "x", where x is an integer.
    void zero(function<void(int)> printNumber) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= this->n; ++i) {
            zero_mtx.lock();

            printNumber(0);

            if (i & 1) {  // odd
                odd_mtx.unlock();

            } else {  // even
                even_mtx.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    void even(function<void(int)> printNumber) {
        for (int a = 2; a <= ((this->n) + 1); a += 2) { // NOTE: `(this->n) + 1` is an rvalue
            even_mtx.lock();

            printNumber(a);

            zero_mtx.unlock();
        }
    }

    void odd(function<void(int)> printNumber) {
        for (int b = 1; b <= ((this->n) + 1); b += 2) { // NOTE: `(this->n) + 1` is an rvalue
            odd_mtx.lock();

            printNumber(b);

            zero_mtx.unlock();
        }
    }
};

// g++ 1116.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread -O0 && ./a.out
int main() {
    printf("helloworld\n");

    ZeroEvenOdd zod(3);

    auto printNumber = [](int x) { cout << x; };

    thread threadA([&]() { zod.zero(printNumber); });
    thread threadB([&]() { zod.even(printNumber); });
    thread threadC([&]() { zod.odd(printNumber); });

    threadA.join();
    threadB.join();
    threadC.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The above program can be compiled and run with `g++ 1116.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread -O0 && ./a.out`, but the program just **hangs without doing anything**. However, if I change the lines

```cpp
for (int a = 2; a <= ((this->n) + 1); a += 2) { // NOTE: `(this->n) + 1` is an rvalue
for (int b = 1; b <= ((this->n) + 1); b += 2) { // NOTE: `(this->n) + 1` is an rvalue
```

to

```cpp
for (int a = 2; a <= ((this->n) + 0); a += 2) {
for (int b = 1; b <= ((this->n) + 0); b += 2) {
```

then **everything works as expected**.

I've tried to reproduce this phenomenon in single thread program, but this behavior doesn't present in single thread program.

I am not sure if this behavior has anything to do with multithreading. I just provide every evidence I have for people to investigate.

**Update:** Change typo `lvalue` to `rvalue`.

Comment: You **may not** `unlock()` a mutex that wasn't `lock()`ed in the current thread.

Comment: From docs: *Unlock: The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.* Prefer a shared mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although locking and unlocking of the mutexes in different threads is **an** issue, it is not **the** issue.

When the loop control is <= ((this->n) + 1), the program proceeds as follows:

1. parent locks even and locks odd;
2. threadB waits for even;
3. threadC waits for odd;
4. threadA locks zero, emits '0', unlocks odd and waits for zero;
5. threadC locks odd, emits '1', unlocks zero and waits for zero;
6. threadA locks zero, emits '0', unlocks even and waits for zero;
7. threadB locks even, emits '2', unlocks zero and waits for even;
8. threadA locks zero, emits '0', unlocks zero and exits;
9. threadC locks odd, emits '3', unlocks zero and exits.

threadB never exits and waits for ever because (a += 2) == 4 and ((this->n) + 1) == 4.

Nothing is emitted because the output remains buffered.

Comment: If it's the case, it will still at least print something (like 0) instead of nothing.

Comment: You are mistaken. By default, cout only physically emits data when it processes a new line character. You can override this default behavior and emit the characters one-by-one by changing printNumber to:

auto printNumber = [](int x) { cout << x; cout.flush(); };

If you do this, the output will become:

helloworld
010203

And then the program will hang and not return control to the shell.

Comment: The difference in behavior of the two original programs is entirely explained by threadB executing two iterations of the "for" loop when the condition is a <= ((this->n) + 1) as compared to a single iteration of the loop when the condition is a <= ((this->n) + 0).

Comment: I appreciate all the comments about `lock()` and `unlock()` of `mutex`. As @Jonno explains, there is a bug in my code.